# Fetch content from API

Tags: python, reactjs, response

My frontend (ReactJS) is located at `localhost:3000` which sends a request to my backend (`localhost:5090/api/fetch/<name>`)

frontend-snippet:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
        //alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5090/api/fetch/' + this.state.value,
            {
                mode: 'no-cors' 
            }).then((response) => console.log(response));

        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

the backend receives the request:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2020 10:54:44] "GET /api/fetch/212 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

and responses with `{"stock": name}`

Python

```
def get(self, name):
        print(name)
        return {"stock": name}
```

however, i'm unable to get the response.

[image]

What am I missing, that I can actualy see the response data of `{"stock": <name>}`?

Answer (score 0):

Sending a request with no-cors returns an opaque type object.

Updating my backend to allow all sources

> What happens with cross-origin requests from frontend JavaScript is that browsers by default block frontend code from accessing resources cross-origin. If Access-Control-Allow-Origin is in a response, then browsers will relax that blocking and allow your code to access the response.

```
from flask_cors import CORS
...
CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

and then removing the mode to `cors` in frontend

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5090/api/fetch/' + this.state.value,
            {
            }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {

                console.log(response)

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error ' + error);
            })
```

successfully displays the data

(response)

```
{stock: "111"}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try like this

```
.then(response => response.json())
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    })
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Error ' + error);
                })
```

Comment: `Error SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Actual code now: `fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5090/api/fetch/' + this.state.value,{mode: 'no-cors'}).then(response => response.json()).then((result) => {console.log(result);}).catch(error => {console.log('Error ' + error);})`

Answer (score -1):

code in Ejaz's answer should work just fine, But I'd recommned you to read the official documentation for fetch api
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

You cant just console.log the response from fetch api it just returns a promise,
you cant print response.body either as it returns a readable stream, Use interface methods on body to read the stream into completion.

You can call response.text() or response.json() depending on type of data your api returns.

Using fetch api, you have to deal with promises, I'll try to refactor your handleSubmit function using async/await, much cleaner way to deal with promises.

```
async handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  try{
    let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5090/api/fetch/'+this.state.value, {
      mode: 'no-cors'});
    console.log(await response.json());
  } 
  catch(error => console.log('Error ' + error));
}
```

Comment: but you'd still need to use response.json() and handle promise returned by it to actually be able to print the response